# Select rows where any column like 'item in a list'/'item in temp table'

Tags: sql, search, oracle11g

I am trying to create a search query that will take a comma separated list of unknown length(search) and select from a table(tableA) all the rows from tableA where some column value in tableA matches item 1 in the search list AND some column value in tableA matches item2 in the search list AND ... all way to itemN in the comma separated list. I know how to do it if I know the length of the list, but not if the list is unbounded.

This is how I would do it if I knew the length of the list, by ANDig groups of OR clauses. This solution does not scale to N items though and I am unsure of how to make the solution scalable

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
WHERE(
    REGEXP_LIKE(tableA.first_name, ('Thing1'), 'i') OR
    REGEXP_LIKE(tableA.last_name, ('Thing1'), 'i') OR
    REGEXP_LIKE(tableA.email_name, ('Thing1'), 'i')
)
AND
(
    REGEXP_LIKE(tableA.first_name, ('Thing2'), 'i') OR
    REGEXP_LIKE(tableA.last_name, ('Thing2'), 'i') OR
    REGEXP_LIKE(tableA.email_name, ('Thing2'), 'i')
)
AND
.
.
.
AND
(
    REGEXP_LIKE(tableA.first_name, ('ThingN'), 'i') OR
    REGEXP_LIKE(tableA.last_name, ('ThingN'), 'i') OR
    REGEXP_LIKE(tableA.email_name, ('ThingN'), 'i')
);
```

The over-arching goal that I want to achieve is that as I enter more items into the search field what is returned is any row, where for every item I have entered in the search field there exists a column in that row that is like the item

Comment: Why do you need separate copies of the clauses?  Shouldn't the regex expression handle that?

Comment: each clause compares 1 item in the search items to all possible columns to search. I couldn't find a way to get the same result with just 1 clase